# How to override the EnvInject plugin variable using SHELL script

Tags: shell, jenkins, environment-variables

I have deployed EnvInjection plugin in jenkins and added below as environment variable

[image]

**Env variable:**

```
env=hello
```

I have below script which is gonna override the `$env` value:

**SHELL Script:**

```
    #!/bin/bash

    n=$(((20 * 100)/15))

    echo "$n"   // return some numeric value.

    export env=$n

    echo $env  # $env variable is overriden as numeric value which is expected.
```

The above script prints 133 numeric value instead of its original value (hello) which is expected.

I tried to use the $env variable in Conditional Step plugin But now It returned hello as variable value.

[image]

The override is working only inside the SHELL script. Is It possible to override that `$env` value permanently by using the SHELL script.

Comment: You can think of Jenkins execute SHELL script within a sandbox which get a copy of all envs, changes envs in SHELL script only take effect within the lifecycle of sandbox.

Comment: Is that not possible to make it change permanently ? Ideally i will get one variable value from some calculator through shell script. I just wanna use it for that value in post build activity/ conditional build plugin to initiate other job. Is there any other way to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write out the vars that after some calculator to a file with content like `var1=value1` (per var per line) in SHELL script, then in Post-build Action load this file to environments.

[image]